# SQL query: SUM(Quantity)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a simple SQL query for an item availability check. My aim is to query the items whose total/summed quantity exceeds the stock level. This is what my table (simplified example) looks like:

| LineNumber | Item | Quantity | StockQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Apple | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Strawberry | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Banana | 1 | 1 |

I have tried it with the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    T1.[LineNumber], T1.[Item], 
    SUM(T1.[Quantity]), T1.[Stockquantity]
FROM 
    Table T1
WHERE 
    T1.[Quantity] > T1.[Stockquantity]
GROUP BY 
    T1.[LineNumber], T1.[Item], T1.[Quantity], T1.[Stockquantity]
```

Does anyone have any advice or tips for me on how I should do this query so that the total/summed quantities per line are compared with the stock quantity and not just the individual/single quantities per line with the stock quantity?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You should include an example of the expected output that matches your example input. From your description it is hard to identify the relationship between `Quantity` and `StockQuantity`. If this is a transaction or invoice table, then we expect that `StockQuantity` is usually a lookup against a ledger of Inventory. I suspect you have oversimplified your example to the point where the necessary detail is now missing.

Comment: bring your desired output result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your extended information in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71452446/1690217 the query you are looking for is this:

```
WITH TotalsLookup as (
    SELECT T1.[VisOrder] as [VisOrder], T1.[U_position] as [ItemGroup-LineNumber]
         , T0.[DocNum] as [DocNumber], T2.[InvntItem], T1.[ItemCode] as [Itemcode]
         , T1.[Quantity], T1.[OpenCreQty] as [openQuantity]
         , T2.[OnHand] as [StockQuantity]
         , SUM(T1.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.[ItemCode] ORDER BY T1.[VisOrder]) AS RunningTotal
    FROM OQUT T0  
    INNER JOIN QUT1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
    INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode] 
)
SELECT VisOrder, [ItemGroup-LineNumber], DocNumber, Itemcode, Quantity, openQuantity, StockQuantity, RunningTotal
FROM TotalsLookup
WHERE DocNumber = '332050' AND [InvntItem] = 'Y' AND RunningTotal > StockQuantity
```

---

#### Original Post

Your example is possibly oversimplified, If `StockQuantity` is the result of a lookup into an inventory, so that in the example we can say the following:

> Total stock on Hand of *Bananas* is 1

And then if you are expecting `LineNumber` 4 to be picked up because this line will make the *`SUM` of **Bananas** greater than the total stock on hand of **Bananas***... then you need a *Running Total* of the `Item` records in this list:

```
WITH TotalsLookup as (
SELECT 
    T1.[LineNumber], T1.[Item], 
    T1.[Quantity], T1.[StockQuantity],
    SUM (T1.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY LineNumber) AS RunningTotal
FROM 
   [Table] T1
)
SELECT * 
FROM TotalsLookup
WHERE RunningTotal > StockQuantity;
```

| LineNumber | Item | Quantity | Stockquantity | RunningTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Banana | 1 | 1 | 2 |

See this Fiddle that covers a few variants of this query and will give you a playground to practice: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a95bb/2

> The origin of `StockQuantity` can itself have a significant impact on the performance and other query options that might be viable, I call this out so that you can be mindful of this when you apply this logic into your application domain, if `StockQuantity` is not a static value, but is itself an aggregate then that may impact how the comparison should be performed.

Comment: Hi Chris,
The idea is really good. I hadn't thought of it before. I would even prefer the runningsum approach now, but unfortunately the partition throws out complete item groups, although I only need individual components. I have specified it further in the answer below.

Comment: @MauriceQuack I have updated the solution, turns out I made a mistake, it was easy to miss when all the values are `1` so I have also updated the fiddle, see how providing different values helps identify issues, your example didn't just simplify the structure, it made the data harder to interpret as well.

Answer (score 0):

your SQL modified code(SQL code didn't work) that does not provide a single output

```
SELECT linenumber,
       a.item,
       quantity,
       SumQuantity,
       stockquantity
FROM   table A
       JOIN(SELECT item,
                   Sum(quantity) SumQuantity,
                   max(stockquantity) stockquantity
            FROM   table C
            GROUP  BY item) B
         ON A.item = B.item
WHERE  SumQuantity> stockquantity
```

ouput

| linenumber | item | quantity | quantity2 | stockquantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | Banana | 1 | 2 | 1 |

However I use the follwing query

```
SELECT String_agg(linenumber, ',') LineNumbers,
       a.item,
       quantity,
       SumQuantity,
       stockquantity
FROM   table  A
       JOIN(SELECT item,
                   Sum(quantity) SumQuantity
                   max(stockquantity) stockquantity
            FROM   table  C
            GROUP  BY item) B
         ON A.item = B.item
WHERE  SumQuantity> stockquantity
GROUP  BY a.item,
          quantity,
          SumQuantity,
          stockquantity
```

that bring following result

| LineNumbers | Item | Quantity | SumQuantity | StockQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,4 | Banana | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: This has a few syntax issues and will pickup both `Banana` items, even though there is enough for one of the records. You have used the same alias `a` twice. Please use more meaningful names https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: `String_Agg` is a novel approach, though you should not be using `a`,`b`,`c` style naming conventions, also your grouping is including `Quantity` which doesn't make a lot of sense  when the `Quantity` column has different values, remember this is an overly simplified example. Also note that the join is not necessary, you could have calculated the aggregate inline in a single query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba578/5

Comment: Hi RF1991, Thank you very much for you answer. It really helps me a lot! 
The first proposal from you is the result I had in mind. I have tried to implement your approach in my real SQL code, unfortunately this has not quite worked yet. Below you can see in my answer how I tried. However, I will keep trying to implement your suggestion correctly in my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to aggregates of a GROUP BY in the having clause

```sql
SELECT 
    T1.[Item], 
    SUM(T1.[Quantity]) As TotalQuantity,
    MAX(T1.[Stockquantity]) AS StockLevel
FROM 
    Table T1
GROUP BY 
    T1.[Item]
HAVING
    SUM(T1.[Quantity]) > MAX(T1.[Stockquantity])
```

This assumes that the `Stockquantity` is the same for all occurrences of a product.

The WHERE clause is executed before grouping, the HAVING clause after grouping.

If you need the line numbers, then you can use the STRING_AGG aggregate function to join the line numbers into a single string per group

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(T1.[LineNumber], ', ') As LineNumbers, ...
```

Comment: It works great. Thank you for this solution. :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have already tried to mark every reply as usable. However, as a new user, this is only possible after a certain number of posts. But I pressed the up arrow anyway. I hope I can do it again soon, once I am a "full" user. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your effort and suggestions for solutions. I have tried to incorporate them all. A few of them worked. With others I still have a few problems:

**@Chris Schaller**
I like you solution a lot! But in my non-simplified, real SQL code, there are item groups that the PARTITION function cannot cope with. My result with your solution is therefore as follows.
However, I will continue to work on it. Thanks!

```
WITH TotalsLookup as (
SELECT T1.[VisOrder] as 'VisOrder', T1.[U_position] as 'ItemGroup-LineNumber', T0.[DocNum] as 'DocNumber', T1.[ItemCode] as 'Itemcode', T1.[Quantity] as 'Quantity', T1.[OpenCreQty] as 'openQuantity', T2.[OnHand] as 'StockQuantity', SUM(T1.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.[ItemCode] ORDER BY T1.[VisOrder]) AS RunningTotal

FROM OQUT T0  
INNER JOIN QUT1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode] 

WHERE T0.[DocNum] = '332050' AND T2.[InvntItem] = 'Y'

)
SELECT * 
FROM TotalsLookup
WHERE RunningTotal > Quantity
```

[Output: here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KnuO.png)

**@RF1991**
I have also tried to implement your solution, but it has not really worked so far. I am still looking for the mistake. Thanks for the help!

```
SELECT T1.[U_position], T1.[ItemCode], T1.[Quantity], T1.[OpenCreQty], T2.[OnHand] 
    
FROM OQUT T0  
INNER JOIN QUT1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode] 
        
JOIN(SELECT T1.[ItemCode], SUM(T1.[Quantity]) as 'SumQuantity', MAX(T2.[OnHand]) as 'Stockquantity' FROM OQUT T0 INNER JOIN QUT1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode]  GROUP BY T1.[ItemCode]) B 
        
ON T1.[ItemCode] = B.[ItemCode]
        
WHERE SumQuantity > stockquantity AND T0.[DocNum] = '332050' AND T2.[InvntItem] = 'Y'
```

**@Oliver Jacot-Descombes**
It works. Thank you very much!

Comment: I made a mistake in my post regarding the comparison, it should be `RunningTotal > StockQuantity`. `PARTITION BY` is very powerful, it can certainly manage this simple grouping that you have shown.

Comment: Now it works as it should. Thanks once again for the hint! :)